# Issue in Rails.application.config.filter_parameters in Rails 7 Rspec

Tags: filter, parameters, rspec, ruby-on-rails-7

When I run `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters` in Rspec in Rails it shows the following result

```
[:card_number, :cvv, :expiry_month, :expiry_year, :number, :password, :password_confirmation, :token, "encrypted_rich_text.body"]
```

`encrypted_rich_text.body` is not present in `filter_parameter_logging.rb` file still it is showing in the Rspec file.

It is working file in `Rails console` but not at the time running the rspec.

at the time of running the command `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters` it should only retrun
`[:card_number, :cvv, :expiry_month, :expiry_year, :number, :password, :password_confirmation, :token`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using `ActiveRecord::Encryption` which will [filter encrypted attributes by default](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#filtering-params-named-as-encrypted-columns) and `ActionText::RichText` which [encrypts the `body` attribute](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f457544f445fc7b0a4d270bcc6428e528bcbd8cf/actiontext/app/models/action_text/encrypted_rich_text.rb#L7) when used with `ActiveRecord::Encryption`.

This is normal behavior. If you do not wish to filter encrypted attributes then set in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```rb
config.active_record.encryption.add_to_filter_parameters = false
```

Or alternatively:

```rb
config.active_record.encryption.excluded_from_filter_parameters = "encrypted_rich_text.body"
```